# Length of geodesic representative on hyperbolic surfaces

Tags: surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

Let $S$ be a closed oriented hyperbolic surface. Let $x,y \in S$ and let $\alpha,\beta$ be two geodesic arcs with endpoints $x$ and $y$. Let $\alpha \beta$ be the closed piecewise geodesic curve obtained from the concatenation of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and let $\gamma$ be the unique closed geodesic freely homotopic to $\alpha \beta$.

Question: is it possible to bound the length of $\gamma$ from below in terms of the length of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: are you looking for an upper or for a lower bound?

Comment: lower bound; something like $l(\gamma) > f(l(\alpha),l(\beta))$ for some function; I have edited the question, thanks

Comment: You are aware of the collar lemma?

Comment: yes; could you explain how it can be used to answer my question?

Comment: I came to know it as a tool to control the length of closed geodesics from below on curvature $-1$ surfaces in the existence proof for so called incompressible minimal surfaces, and I got the impression it is pretty close to what you can get in this direction. But it has been a while. There is a paper of Tomi/Tromba in which this is done (in the eighties). Since you got a negative answer to your question it may be a means to find out what you can expect. That's just it from my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no bound of this sort. Or, to put it more precisely, the only bound you can have of this sort is the length of a shortest simple closed geodesic, which is a constant for the surface and which does not depend in any way on the lengths of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

To see why, start from $\gamma$ being a shortest simple closed geodesic on $S$, which implies that $\gamma$ is a shortest closed geodesic (whether simple or not).

Let $x,z \in \gamma$ be antipodal points of $\gamma$, meaning that they subdivide $\gamma$ into two equal segments. Denote those two segments $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ with initial endpoint $x$ and terminal endpoint $z$. Let $\delta$ be a geodesic path with initial endpoint $z$ and terminal endpoint $y$; this path $\delta$ can be as long as you like, a gajillion bazillion light years long.

Now let $\alpha$ be the geodesic path which is path homotopic to $\gamma_1 \delta$ and let $\beta$ be the geodesic path which is path homotopic to $\gamma_2 \delta$. Each of these two paths has length greater than or equal to $\text{Length}(\delta) - \frac{1}{2} \text{Length}(\gamma)$, which can be as long as you like.

Now concatenate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (you wrote the concatenation incorrectly as $\alpha\beta$, so let me correct that to $\alpha\bar\beta$). The conclusion is that the unique closed geodesic that is freely homotopic to $\alpha\bar\beta$ is simply $\gamma$, which is the shortest closed geodesic of them all.

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer. There's a point I don't get. $\gamma_1 \delta$ is a path from $x$ to $y$, and $\alpha$ is the geodesic path which is path homotopic to $\gamma_1 \delta$, so I would expect it to be shorter than $\gamma_1 \delta$, i.e. $L(\alpha)\leq \dfrac{1}{2}L(\gamma)+L(\delta)$. But you wrote an inequality which is equivalent to $L(\delta)\leq \dfrac{1}{2}L(\gamma)+L(\alpha)$...how do you get it?

Comment: @Lor: There is a triangle at issue here, whose sides $\gamma_1$, $\delta$, $\alpha$ concatenate up to form a homotopically trivial closed curve, and from this we get three triangle inequalities for path length. You are thinking of the triangle inequality whose left hand side is $L(\alpha)$, whereas I am thinking instead of the triangle inequality whose left hand side is $L(\delta)$, namely $L(\delta) \le L(\gamma_1) + L(\alpha)$.